# jQuery is not working with Chaplin

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, requirejs, chaplinjs

I am working in some Backbone Framework - Chaplin where i am using following list of files:

Following is some of the code block in main.js:

```
paths: {
        jquery: 'vendors/jquery/jquery',
        underscore: 'vendors/underscore/underscore',
        backbone: 'vendors/backbone/backbone',
        chaplin: 'vendors/chaplin-0.9.0',        
        bootstrap: 'vendors/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min',        
        jqTriggers: 'lib/jquery-triggers'
    },

shim: {
        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        },
        backbone: {
            deps: ['jquery','underscore'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        bootstrap: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },        
        jqTriggers: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
```

Following are the contents in jquery-triggers.js

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {

   $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown(); 

});
```

Following is the code block of an template file using Bootstrap framework:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse nav">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="brand" href="/">Project Name</a>

                <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                  <ul class="nav">
                      <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                      <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-home icon-white"></i> Home</a></li>                      
                  </ul>
                  <div class="pull-right">
                    <ul class="nav pull-right">
                        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Welcome, User <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="/user/preferences"><i class="icon-cog"></i> Preferences</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/help/support"><i class="icon-envelope"></i> Contact Support</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="/auth/logout"><i class="icon-off"></i> Logout</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Problem: The drop-down is 'dropdown' menu is not working.

I guess! the jquery-triggers.js is not loading. because i am not able to see it gets loaded on Chrome / firefox firebug network / net respectively.

I tried including jquery-triggers.js file in my index.html page after the require.js inclusion but it did not worked as jquery-triggers.js files gets loaded early.

Comment: try depending on jqTriggers

Comment: I tried but not working

Comment: define(['jqTriggers'], function(jqTriggers) {

   $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown(); 

});  But this is not working either.

Comment: Get any errors? Really you should be passing `jquery` and `jqTriggers` as dependencies.

Comment: I would have suggested the same.  The reason `jqTriggers` doesn't get loaded is because you haven't used it anywhere!  `define(['jqTriggers'], ...)` with the shim should take care of that by loading `jQuery` followed by `jqTriggers`.  It's difficult to debug beyond that without any further info.

Answer (score 0):

Pass jqTriggers into the required array for the whole application.

It will then be loaded everywhere.

```
require(['application', 'routes', 'jqTriggers'], 
  function (Application, routes) {
     var app = new Application({
     routes: routes,
     controllerSuffix: '-controller'
   });          
});
```